# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Line 3:1:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions. This is my first time using 'use restrict" in javascript and I don't know how to fix the rule that is against.

**My Nav.js file in react**

```
import React from 'react';

'use strict';
function Nav() {
  return (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> About </li>
            <li> Shop </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#invoking_strict_mode):

> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) before any other statements.

Since you put that string literal after your `import`s, it is **just** a string literal expression. It doesn't trigger strict mode. It doesn't do *anything* (because you don't assign it / pass it / etc).

Move it so it is the **very first line** of your JS.

Comment: …also, since this is a module (using `import` syntax), it already is strict mode, so the directive should be omitted entirely

Comment: @Quentin, the error went off. I see your expert in javascript. Should I only use strict mode or add typescript with strict mode to check errors better and improve my code?

Comment: @Bergi, I see that after I follow Quentin's instruction and a link provided for solution